# Facebook Graph API check page visitor posts' author

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, author

I am currently trying to get the visitor posts of my development page with Graph API Explorer (v5.0), and I cannot get the authors (from) of the posts but it does not show it. 
[image]
I switched to Page access token, and added all the possible permissions.

How can I get it to show the author of the visitor posts?